# Call controller method from outside the controller

Tags: ios, methods, controller

I have an implementation of the `RenderTone` method for sound playback and from that method I want to call controller methods. I'm able to acces controller members fine like this:

```
InstrumentGridViewController *viewController = (InstrumentGridViewController *)inRefCon;
viewController->count = 7;
```

But what I want to do is call a method the same way. I tried this but it's not working:

```
viewController->stopToneUnit;
```

My method implementation looks like this:

```
- (void) stopToneUnit{
    AudioOutputUnitStop(toneUnit);
    AudioUnitUninitialize(toneUnit);
    AudioComponentInstanceDispose(toneUnit);
    toneUnit = nil;
}
```

How should I call this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C the syntax for sending messages is:

```
[viewController stopToneUnit];
```